Parsing 深夜早朝の時間帯に限り、予め指定した2つまでの電話番号に対し、通話時間に関わらず料金が月極の一定料金となる
I was reading the Wikipedia page about テレホーダイ and there is one sentence I am not sure how to parse:

深夜早朝の時間帯（23時から翌日8時まで）に限り、予め指定した2つまでの電話番号に対し、通話時間に関わらず料金が月極の一定料金となる。

It seems like 深夜早朝の時間帯に限り, 予め指定した2つまでの電話番号に対し and 通話時間に関わらず all modify 料金が月極の一定料金となる, right? But I cannot make sense of it. I think the whole sentence means "The service fee becomes set fee that needs to be paid every month, and the service paid by this fee will be used between 11pm to 8am, and a user can get up to two designated phone numbers, and there is no limit on how much the service is used"?

It's slightly unclear where you're stuck (maybe it's 月極{つきぎめ} you're having trouble?), but

深夜早朝の時間帯（23時から翌日8時まで）に限り、

Only from night till early mornling (23-08),


予め指定した2つまでの電話番号に対し、

for the (up to) two phone numbers the user has designated,


通話時間に関わらず

regardless of how long you talk over the phone,


料金が月極の一定料金となる

The fee is monthly contract and is fixed  = The user pays a fixed amount billed monthly (= it's {certain amount} yen/month, fixed)



So basically, (1) The service is billed monthly, (2) you specify up to two numbers (that you would like to call) beforehand, (3) then, from 23 in the evening to 8 in the morning, (4) you can make phone calls as much and as long as you want for the two numbers you have specified.
The premise is that if you call outside of the hours or other numbers, you'll be billed in a pay-as-you-go manner.
